# Are answers up-voted distinctly more frequent than questions?

Tags: discussion, voting, upvotes

Looking at many questions like just sorting "all questions" by votes it seems to me like many answers gain - at least slightly - more up-votes than  question itself (however, I did not take a look at if there were many down-votes for a question just the total).

And if not a single answer then there are usually many answers having lots of up-votes so if assuming that not so many voters up-vote 2 or three answers there are more distinct up-voters to answers.

Of course I realize that there could be a bad / wrongly asked question with an excellent answer but maybe not so many?

Can some statistic guru provide some proof to support/not support my assumption which is:

**There are more distinct up-voters for answers than for questions for those answers?**

*Or is this actually impossible since voting should be closed so without knowing voter identity distinction can not be made?*

In that case maybe some statistics about Q&A where there is just a single answer having top count of votes, maybe?

Comment: That would make sense I guess as people generally only want the answer (solution). I, for one noticed that whenever I used to find a solution to an issue I was facing on SO I'd frequently up-vote the answer and close the tab whereas now I actively try and up-vote both the question and answer.

Comment: I would imagine that questions are down-voted more often than answers, since downvoting answers is disincentived through a rep cost.

Comment: You can check [the Nice/Good/Great Question/Answer badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) for a rough comparison, but there are more answers on the site as a whole, so that's probably a bit misleading.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you sort "by votes", you are actually sorting "by score".

Comment: Considering there's a hell of a lot more of one than the other, it stands to reason that the one will receive more total upvotes. Along with the fact that it's far more likely for an answer to be useful than for a question to be useful.

Comment: @KevinB Just thinking that would there be any answers - good or bad - without a question? And if question is seldom useful why even have a possibility to upvote?

Comment: Of course not... but that doesn't mean the question should be upvoted. usefulness also isn't the only reason one might cast an upvote.

Comment: @KevinB I agree but actually I m not claiming that or asking if it is so but the real statistics if possible. Also take a look at my comment to answer from MonkeyZeus.

Comment: I don't understand how that comment is relevant to mine.

Comment: @KevinB I just meant that I realize that also quality issues etc... will affect in addition to usefulness or so but that aspect is left out on purpose.

Comment: i mean... if you leave that aspect out, you'll never get a clear picture. you can't just ignore one of the two primary reasons people vote.

Comment: @KevinB The problem is: how do you measure the quality? By voting? Then if the statistics show my assumption correct, is it ok to say that questions are like most of the time lower quality than answers? But anyway, this is not my question.

Comment: You don't measure either, because they aren't measureable. All we have is the fact that a vote was cast or not.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Why aren't people voting for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions)

Comment: @AndrewT. Nice finding. I just wonder where did the statistics come, any clue?

Comment: @pirho it's a very old stats (10 years ago!), but you can use advanced search for [questions with score 0 or 1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+score%3A0..1) and [questions with score 2 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+score%3A2..), then divide them with [all questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks, your comment is the first real attempt to answer to my actual question in addition to Alexei Levenkovs answer. People for some reason tend to read the title of question like "Why questions are not upvoted, I am very angry about that".

Answer (score 6):

I sure as heck know I am guilty of this.

More often than not an answer is more impressive than the question because the answerer exhibited some level of ingenuity.

Questions, albeit probably unique, are usually along the lines of "Halp! I don't understand what I did wrong after following this YouTube tutorial."

Comment: Yes I agree to some extent. Actually I was thinking about to add something like "and also many questions seem to be at least as good quality as answers " but it might have launched some debat about quality which is not my purpose. Also there has been some discussions about why somebody give a good quality answer to a bad quality question instead of bettering question or commenting the poor quality of question instead of answering to it. But +1 for honesty ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that this is by design.

The system makes a point of emphasis on the best *answers* and specifically searching for *answers*.  There's even an oft-referenced document [which again, emphasizes answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) as the thing we focus on here.

By design, the thing we focus on the most gets the most attention, and would result in higher vote rates.

If you wanted to compare one-to-one between questions and answer voting, you would have to weigh questions differently, which gets *weird*.  You get 5 rep for an upvote on a question and 10 rep for an answer.  You can either double the rep on questions or half the rep on answers, which again gets *weird* since questions and answers have mutually exclusive importance in the hierarchy.

<sup>Yes, I know answers don't happen without questions, but questions aren't worth anything without answers.</sup>

Comment: Nice answer until the last sentence. Oh man! Do you read only pragmatic philosophers? I would say that at least 70% of my knowledge is based on curiosity that somebody's question has initiated, I would never had the idea that that kind of a problem even existed! Well in a sense Q&A are inseparable. but  even if I do not have the answer to some specific question I surely have learned something else while trying to answer to it.

Comment: @pirho:  I'm really happy that you learned something, but I'm trying to *solve* something here.  The general use case is that people use the site to solve a problem, and if someone else has the *same* problem **and there is no solution**, we're no better off than some God-forsaken phpBB forum post from 2005 with the exact same error code you're seeing in 2019.

Comment: I see your point. And I might have to mentioned that like 95% of the cases I also provide the answer - was it then good or bad - but also I bump into questions that really give me totally new aspect & approach to my own problem even I do not like the answer or question is not a duplicate to my own. I admit that is more rare case but still.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds plausible that answers upvoted more. For in less popular or new questions it is very easy to see if answer actually provides correct and useful answer to the question than to see if question is useful by itself. Most new questions visited by people who plan to answer/moderate rather than have that particular question.

Additional points to consider:

- author of the question can't upvote the question but have no reasons not to upvote answers when there is more than one.
- downvotes on questions are free. There is very large number of posts that show "no research effort" driving number of downvotes on questions up
- generally people provide answers that at least somewhat helpful and try to fix/delete they answers if approach turned out to be wrong.
- downvotes on answers cost 2 points. Combined with previous it makes number of downvotes on answers lower (as post need to be really wrong).

Comment: Downvotes on answers cost **2** points? I did my duty earlier today and I only see a `-1` in my rep.

Answer (score 2):

It happens like this: I seek an answer. Google finds and links me to the answer - I don't even have to see the question at this point, for all I care the question does not even exist. I skim the answers instead and apply the one that seems the most relevant. It works, I upvote the answer and happily hit the back button to go back to Google.

I then have to actively remember: oh wait, *what about the question?* Go back, scroll up to the question and judge it's quality. Because I have to make an active effort to do so... sometimes I don't. Probably half the times I don't. Its just the way it is.